# How to display Dynamic data on HIGHCHARTS? I used JSON Generator but not displayed anything,

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, sfdc-styleguide

Here is my Snippet,I don't get any Javascript errors but my graph is displayed simply without populating data.

Any one help me where i am wrong

### VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="JSON5" >
     <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Highstock, '/js/jquery.min.js')}"/>  
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Highstock, 'js/highstock.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Highstock, 'js/modules/exporting.js')}"/>
     <script language="JavaScript1.2" src="/js/functions.js"></script>
     <script src="/soap/ajax/9.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked column chart'
            },
            xAxis: {!Prettys},
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',

                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -30,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 25,
                floating: true,

                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
                shared: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'percent',

                }
            },
            series: [!prettyq]
        });
    });



    </script>

     <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
     </div>

     </apex:page>
```

---

### Controller

```
public  class JSON5 {

      public boolean startGen = true;
    public string prettyq{get;set;}
    public string Prettys{get;set;}

     public JSON5(){
         list<decimal> rev8 = new list<decimal>();
      list<decimal> rev9 = new list<decimal>();
      list<decimal> rev11= new list<decimal>();
      list<string> names = new list<string>();
         string rev1 = 'Annual Revenue 2009';

          JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(startgen);
          JSONGenerator rname = JSON.createGenerator(startgen);


         for(Opportunity optobj:[select id,name,Revenue_2008__c,Revenue_2009__c,Revenue_2011__c from opportunity limit 10])
         {
              if(optobj.Revenue_2008__c == null)
              {
                  optobj.Revenue_2008__c = 0;
              }
             if(optobj.Revenue_2009__c == null)
              {
                  optobj.Revenue_2009__c =0;
              }
             if(optobj.Revenue_2011__c == null)
              {
                  optobj.Revenue_2011__c =0;
              }

             rev8.add(optobj.Revenue_2008__c);
             rev9.add(optobj.Revenue_2009__c);
             rev11.add(optobj.Revenue_2011__c);
             names.add(optobj.Name);

         }             


                  gen.writeStartObject();
                  gen.writeStringField('Name','Annual Revenue 2008' );
                   gen.writeObjectField('Data',rev8);
               gen.writeEndObject();

          gen.writeStartObject();
                  gen.writeStringField('Name','Annual Revenue 2009' );
                   gen.writeObjectField('Data',rev9);
               gen.writeEndObject();



          gen.writeStartObject();
                  gen.writeStringField('Name','Annual Revenue 2011' );
                   gen.writeObjectField('Data',rev11);
               gen.writeEndObject();




          rname.writeStartObject();
         rname.writeObjectField('Names',names);
         rname.writeEndObject();         
         prettyq = gen.getAsString();
         Prettys = rname.getAsString();

          System.debug('Json Account Structure:'+prettyq);
         System.debug('Json Account Structure:'+prettys);

     }
}
```

This is What need to display

[image: This is What need to display,]

Debug Logs
[image: Debug Logs]

Comment: wat does ur chart look like now ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at your code and somehow did not get the JSON as you mentioned.

I checked with loading data in 2 opportunity records ( for testing ), I got this result
Json Account Structure:"{\"Name\":\"Annual Revenue 2008\",\"Data\":[23,10]} {\"Name\":\"Annual Revenue 2009\",\"Data\":[43,20]} {\"Name\":\"Annual Revenue 2011\",\"Data\":[65,26]}"

It had 2 problems 
1. The '\' is not required for end result, you may want to replace/remove the '\'  
 prettyq = prettyq.replace('\', ''); 
 prettys = prettys.replace('\', ''); 
 2. The individual records are not comma separated. You can add them in array
 gen.writeStartArray();
 your code for gen  objects
 gen.writeEndArray();

Although you attached a screenshot, but your code lacked above points. You may please check again.
 
 3. Use series: {!prettyq}  and  xAxis: {!prettys} 
 in VF page

4. I was testing in chrome and it blocked the JS charts, please check it does not block for you also.

   5. Also, use small character for fields like name, data 
      Instead of         gen.writeStringField('Name','Annual Revenue 2008' );
                 gen.writeObjectField('Data',rev8);  
      use                gen.writeStringField('name','Annual Revenue 2008' );
                 gen.writeObjectField('data',rev8);   
      I think I read somewhere the fields are case sensitive.

   Please get back if the above suggestions did not work for you. I have tried and it works.

   If the above analysis helps in resolution of your problem, please select it as the best answer.

Rgds,
Dave

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I tried all your suggestions and i removed that  '\' by making few changes in  my JSON string and called the JSON string in another getMethod it s working fine, Once again,  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am glad it helped you!